# How do I array push this 2-D array? (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

In this codeigniter model, I am trying to push the category name of each product. 
I want the array to look like:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => Game 1!
        [category_id] => 3
        [category] => games //the category element is in the [0] array.
    )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Game 2
            [category_id] => 3
            [category] => games
        )
```

here's how the array looks right now:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [category] => games //i want this to be in the [1] array
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => Game 1!
        [category_id] => 3
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [category] => games
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [name] => Game 2
        [category_id] => 3
    )
```

here's my function that gets all the products and puts them in the array.

```
function getAllProducts(){
    $data=array();
    $Q=$this->db->get('products');
    if($Q->num_rows() > 0){
        foreach($Q->result_array() as $row){
            $Q2=$this->db->query("select name FROM categories 
            where id={$row['category_id']}");
            if($Q2->num_rows() > 0){
                foreach($Q2->result_array() as $row2){
                    //Trouble Here: dont know how to push this into the array.
                    //is there a function that i can put in the $data[___] 
                    //area so that it knows it is in the [0] element, then [1],etc?
                    $data[]['category']=$row2['name'];  
                }

            }    
            $data[]=$row;
        }
    }
    $Q->free_result();
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either do:

```
foreach($Q->result_array() as $key=>$row){
        $data[$key]=$row;
        $Q2=$this->db->query("select name FROM categories 
        where id={$row['category_id']}");
        if($Q2->num_rows() > 0){
            foreach($Q2->result_array() as $row2){
                $data[$key]['category']=$row2['name'];  
            }

        }    

    }
```

**or even better, make the right query:**

```
function getAllProducts(){
    $data=array();
    $Q=$this->db->query("SELECT p.*, c.name as category FROM products p, LEFT JOIN categories c  ON c.id=p.category_id");
    if($Q->num_rows() > 0){
        foreach($Q->result_array() as $row){
             $data[] = $row;
        }
    }
    $Q->free_result(); // <- needed here? don't know
    return $data;
}
```

I don't know CodeIgniter, so I don't know whether this is totally correct. But in general this is much better, as you reduce the number of DB access which is **always** good.
This way, you have only **one** query instead of `n+1` if you have `n` products.

P.S.: I bet CodeIgniter also provides some APIs to make a `JOIN`. Read the [documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html).

I just saw, that you could do this:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('products');
$this->db->join('categories', 'categories.id = products.category_id', 'left');

$Q = $this->db->get();
```

Make use of the API.

Comment: You are a genius. I can't believe I overlooked the $key=>$row. Thank you very much. If I ever meet you, I'll buy you a beer :)

Comment: @ggfan: Alright ;) But **please** consider the second approach... it is **much** better performance wise.

Answer (score 1):

I would try a different approach that reduces the number of total queries you need to make.

```
$productRows = getAllProducts();
$categoryRows = getAllCategories();

$categoriesById = array();

foreach ($categoryRows as $categoryRow) {

    $categoriesById[$categoryRow['id']] = $categoryRow;
}

$productsWithCategory = array();

foreach ($productRows as $productRow) {

    $categoryId = $productRow['category_id'];
    $productsWithCategory[] = array(
                 'id' => $productRow['id'],
               'name' => $productRow['name'],
        'category_id' => $categoryId,
           'category' => $categoriesById[$categoryId]['name']
    );
}
```